# Why isn't my typedef inherited?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typedef

I have the following code, which doesn't compile:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    typedef int A_t;
};

template<class T>
class IB {
public:
    typedef typename T::A_t B_t;
    virtual B_t get() = 0;
protected:
    B_t v;
    IB(B_t in) : v(in) { }
};

template<class T>
class B : public IB<T> {
public:
    B(B_t in) : IB<T>(in) { }   // error: expected ')' before 'in'
    B_t get() { return B_t(); } // error: B_t does not name a type
};

int main() {
    B<A> a(3);  // Errors here since int can't be converted to const B& or const B&&
                // Also because A is virtual, since A::get() doesn't compile
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can understand the error messages, the main problem is that the `typedef` in `IB` for some reason isn't available in `B`.

If I add a line `typedef IB<T>::B_t B_t;` above the `B` constructor, the code compiles OK, but I don't understand *why* I need this. Shouldn't `B_t` be available through inheritance?

Also, the following doesn't work either:

```cpp
B(IB<T>::B_t in) : IB<T>(in) { }
// etc, with qualified references to B_t
```

yields the same error messages.

What is the mechanism here that prevents me from using `B_t` it in `B` without the extra `typedef`?

Comment: @RogerRowland Yup, this is a dupe. Thanks for finding it for me!